# How do i get conversation to display at the bottom by default where recent messages are present when entering chat screen?

Tags: swift, messagekit

After tapping on a conversation, the chat screen will start at the top and then scroll all the way to the bottom. How can i bypass starting at the top and the scrolling to immediately displaying the most recent message at the bottom.
This line of code is the closest thing i have found to doing what i want

```
messagesCollectionView.scrollToLastItem(animated: true)
```

This is how it's currently displaying and then it will scroll to the bottom when i enter into the conversation (notice date)

[image]

This is how i want it do display upon entering the conversation (notice date)

[image: This is]

```
 private func listenForMessages(id: String) {
        Networking.shared.getComments(requestId: 15836, completionHandler: { [weak self] (result) in
            switch result {
            case .success(let comments):
                guard !comments.isEmpty else {
                    return
                }
                
                self?.messages = comments
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self?.messagesCollectionView.reloadData()
                    self?.messagesCollectionView.scrollToLastItem()
                    
                } 
            case .failure(let error):
                print("failed to get messages: \(error)")
            }
    })
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You would probably just be able to say `animated: false` in that line.

Comment: hmm no still does it

Comment: Can you include more code? Like where is that `scrollToBottom` line?

Comment: @goatfanerd yep just included a snippet

Answer (score 0):

You've not posted what you're doing in `scrollToLastItem`, you can try this though:

```
 let lastItemIndex = IndexPath(item: collectionArray.count - 1, section: 0)
            self.collectionView.scrollToItem(at: lastItemIndex, at: .bottom, animated: false)
```